# Difference between licensed and demo Kendo UI for angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

what is the difference between licensed and demo Kendo UI for angular ?

Can anyone tell me what is difference?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comparison of the 2 versions so you can see the available components

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/comparison